# use svnlook proplist / propget in svn post hook

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

I have added a property to my SVN using:

```
svn propset MyProp "MyValue" .
```

and i did commit it:

```
svn ci -m "add some prop stuff..."
```

but now I try to read this property in a post-commit hook:

```
/usr/bin/svnlook proplist $1 -t $2 --verbose .
```

but all I get is: nothing. What's wrong there? There should be a property...

Answer (score 0):

In post-commit hook you have already revision, not transaction